# Null pointer execption at this piece of code

Tags: android

Hi i am new to android and i am getting Null pointer Exception.can any body tell me the problem with this code 
The code is as below.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pd = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
    //pd.setTitle("Sending Request !");
    pd.setMessage(ActivityStrings.PROGRESS_MESSAGE_PD);
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);

    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    if (!((Activity) mContext).isFinishing()) {
        pd.show();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

See log cat here

```
            05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329): java.lang.NullPointerException
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:142)
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at com.eeshana.android_29042014.AsynkTask.GuestLoginSenderAskTask.onPreExecute(GuestLoginSenderAskTask.java:72)
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at com.eeshana.android_04012014.checkthisapp.LoginScreen.callGuestLoginThread(LoginScreen.java:138)
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at com.eeshana.android_04012014.checkthisapp.LoginScreen.onClick(LoginScreen.java:104)
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    05-31 01:57:12.568: E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your logcat then.

Comment: Looking at your code the only possible object that could be throwing that error is the mContext. It probably hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: What is `mContext` and where your `initialized` it?

Comment: Please check line number 138 and 104 in LoginScreen.java. on that line of code its getting null value

Comment: waht is line no. 72 ,?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi by looking your code i guess it's the problem of mContext in you code as Stated by @Wezelkrozum. As a solution I can say your mContext is pointing to the Null. If you are using mContext to initialize Context everywhere then just do this.mContext = yourContext(Obj).
I think this will work...

Answer (score 1):

This is simple logic Just use this.mContext to initialize your Context. It will me done...

Answer (score 0):

Given the stacktrace you posted the problem seems to be in the init on the alert dialog as stated by this line:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(8329):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
```

This probably means that the variable mContext is null when the following line of your code is being executed:

```
pd = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
```

The most reasonable way to solve your problem is to define the AsyncTask (I am assuming is an async task as it defines the method onPreExecute) like this:

```
 public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Context mContext;

    public MyAsyncTask(Context ctx) {
          this.mContext = ctx;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String returnedValue; 
        //your long-time-taking code goes here.
        return returnedValue;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       //do something with the returned value and eventually hide the progress bar
       pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       super.onPreExecute();
       pd = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
       pd.setMessage(ActivityStrings.PROGRESS_MESSAGE_PD);
       pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
       pd.setCancelable(false);
       pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
       if (!((Activity) mContext).isFinishing()) {
           pd.show();
       }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
       // do something while the task is running, such updating your progress bar..
    }
}
```

And to initialise it (in your activity) like this:

```
new MyAsyncTask(this).execute(STRING_PARAMETER);
```

That way you will have a proper context in your async task to initialise your progress dialog.

Few points here:

1. The asynctask example above gets a string as parameter and
   returns a string as result (you can easily override this behaviour
   depending on your needs)
2. You can pass the activity to the asynctask in order to define some kind of callback to give back control to the activity (as an example, to update the view)
3. When you rotate your device the activity is getting recreated by the OS and your asynctask will thus **not** be able to perform any callback to it (use a Loader instead).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix NullPointException by check crush line uses object ref is null or not.

Then try to init that object ref before you call it.

This case like mContext <- this object maybe is null , you should init mContext before you new ProgressDialog.

if in MainActivity like this

```
mContext = MainActivity.this; // <- your context instance.
pd = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
```